# user profile changes not reflected

Tags: user-profile

Say,  i have 100 users in user profile.

Requirement : Get all user profile changes from a given date-time value to Now(date time) in a collection .Iterate collection to do the necessary changes.
Problem : If i am updating some user profile say , A. Then i am not able to get the changes when i am calling UserProfileChangeCollection with the specified time of the token.
Question :  Do i need to restart any service or timer job to make the changes appear in the UserProfileChangeCollection  immediately. 
[I am able to see the changes some 24 hr later. ]

Any idea.

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing what you're trying to do, but I believe once a change has been pushed to UPS, the "User Profile Change Job" timer job has to run. With the default configuration this runs hourly.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out this thread which covers how to setup the farm for tracing User Profile changes:  [Tracing user profile changes without iterating all the through?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17756/tracing-user-profile-changes-without-iterating-all-the-through)

Comment: I referred it earlier. I followed the steps to enable logging.Still not able to get the later changes.