# Unused MySites in SP2013 - how to identify them?

Tags: 2013, powershell, my-site, governance

I want to regularly remove MySites which have been created and remain unused (i.e. never accessed).

Ideally the criteria for this would be:

- Created more than 7 days ago (Which I can get using CertificationDate, I think)
- Never accessed

I can't see how to do this.  I've looked at the MySite Site Collection properties in SharePoint Manager, and has a sort of half-baked idea involving lastsecuritymodified and lastcontentmodified but it came to nothing.

So my questions are as follows:

a. Can this be done?

b. If not, why not?

c. If so, what can I check to make this happen?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The built in MySite cleanup job handles this automatically:

> What is the My Site Cleanup Timer Job
>
> The My Site Cleanup Job is
> responsible for deleting user profiles and My Sites of those users.
> This includes the following activities:
>
> - Remove user profiles that are
>   queued for deletion.
> - If those users have a My Site, assign the  user’s
>   manager as the SPSite.SecondaryContact.
> - Email the manager letting
>   them know that the user’s My Site will be deleted in 14 days.
> - 11 days
>   after the first notification, email the manager again letting them
>   know that the My Site will be deleted in 3 days.
> - After a total of 14
>   days, delete the MySite.

[Source](http://sharepoint2013admin.wordpress.com/2013/11/19/my-site-cleanup-timer-job/)

More here, for 2010 but it's the same in 2013, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2012/06/25/top-recommendations-for-managing-the-my-site-cleanup-timer-job.aspx

Comment: Robert, thanks.  The users and their profiles aren't going anywhere, just their (unused) mysites.  It's the site I need to get rid of.

Comment: Why would you want to delete the sites for existing users? Users content and feed information is stored there

Comment: It's my understanding that users don't have a mysite until they provision it themselves.  So if they provision it and then don't use it, no content is added?  However we have allocated a certain amount of space for that mysite, which we'd like to reclaim.

Answer (score 0):

Related questions is here
[Tracing user profile changes without iterating all the through?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17756/tracing-user-profile-changes-without-iterating-all-the-through/20092#20092)

You could activate your profile change tracking and then access the user change object to get at that data.  I would consider the reason for doing so - if they have not done anything with it the footprint is minimal.  If there is a chance they will be using it in the future then it's better to leave it there vs. having to reprovision it.

One more reason - every now and then SharePoint won't recognize that you have deleted the mysite and instead of creating a new one will show the user an error.  Then you will need to go in and manually correct the issue.